# Overriding a hash and making [] operators private - cant use ||= anymore

Tags: ruby, operators, overriding

Test code:

```
class PrivHash < Hash
  def set(key, val)
     self[key] = val
  end
  def set_maybe(key, val)
    self[key] ||= val
  end
  private
  def []= key, value 
  end
  def [] key
    super            
  end
end
```

With this code, I expect both `set` and `set_maybe` to work. However, only `set` works and `set_maybe` fails with:

```
[30] pry(#<TranslationInfo>):1> ph.set_maybe(:a, 1)
NoMethodError: private method `[]' called for {:a=>2}:#Class:0x007f99c5924c38>::PrivHash 
from (pry):56:in `set_maybe'
```

I assumed that `self[:b] ||= <x>` is just syntactic sugar for `self[:b] || self[:b] = <x>`, but I guess it isn't because this works.

What bugs me is why I am getting this error.. I am executing this from within the class so why am I getting private method error?

Comment: I didn't get this error message (Ruby 2.2.4). Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: Getting the error in 2.3.0.

Comment: I indeed observe the same behavior, under ruby 2.3. The `||=` fails whereas the `self[key] || self[key] = val` version works. Under ruby 2.2 *both* versions work. Apparently the `||=` is **not** just a syntactic sugar for the other version...

Comment: @BoraMa that's right, it's not equivalent. `self[key] ||= val` evaluates `key` once, whereas `self[key] || self[key] = val` may evaluate `key` twice.

Comment: @user1934428 I am facing this in 1.9.3

Comment: What is `ph`? What is your question?

Comment: @sawa: `ph = PrivHash.new`. And the question is, presumably, why does it not work in 2.3.0 or 2.1.1 (by my tests) nor in 1.9.3 (by OP's), but it does work in 2.2.0 or 2.2.4 and JRuby (1.7.11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling of private methods is a bit of a mess, currently.

The *original* rule was:

> private methods can only be called without an explicit receiver.

This is a nice, simple, easily understandable rule. It is also a *static* rule, i.e. it can be checked without running the code, in fact, it is even a *syntactic* rule, it doesn't even need sophisticated static analysis, it can be checked in the parser.

However, it was soon noticed that this rule makes it impossible to call private setters, since setters can't be called without an explicit receiver (`foo = bar` is a setting a local variable, not calling a setter). Ergo, the rule was extended:

> private methods can only be called without an explicit receiver, unless the method call is an assignment method call, in which case the method can also be called with an explicit receiver as long as that explicit receiver is the literal pseudo-variable `self`.

This allows you to call private setters with an explicit receiver of the literal value `self`:

```
self.foo = bar
```

but not a dynamic value of `self`

```
baz = self
baz.foo = bar # NoMethodError: private method `foo=' called
```

This still preserves the property that private method calls can be detected at parse time.

Two years ago, [I filed a bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9907) about abbreviated method assignments not working, i.e.:

```
self.foo += bar # NoMethodError
```

That bug was fixed by again extending the rule for private method calls (and now the rule is already getting so complex that I'm not going to spell it out).

However, there are still a lot of cases left that are not covered by the existing rules, where methods simply cannot syntactically be called without an explicit receiver and thus cannot be private:

```
self[foo]
!self
self + foo
```

etc.

Some of those have been fixed, some haven't. The problem is that the rule has now gotten so complex that it is hard to implement correctly. [There have been proposals to change the rule](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11297) to something like this:

> private methods can only be called without an explicit receiver or an explicit receiver which is the literal pseudo-variable `self`.

That is a nice, simple, easily understandable rule, can be statically checked at parse time, and has none of the complex exceptions and corner cases we have currently. It is, however, not yet implemented AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to decompile it.

```
code = <<CODE
class PrivHash < Hash
  def set(key, val)
    self[key] = val
  end
  def set_maybe(key, val)
    self[key] ||= val
  end
  private
  def []= key, value 
  end
  def [] key
    super            
  end
end
CODE
disasm = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(code).disasm
File.write("#{RUBY_VERSION}.txt", disasm)
```

Based on the results, I conclude the issue is this: 2.2.0 calls

```
0010 opt_aref         <callinfo!mid:[], argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>
...
0013 branchif         25
...
0020 opt_aset         <callinfo!mid:[]=, argc:2, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>
```

Basically, evaluate `[]`, see if it's falsy, and if so, call `[]=`. But 2.3.0 doesn't use `FCALL` flag on the `[]` call:

```
0010 opt_aref         <callinfo!mid:[], argc:1, ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
...
0014 branchif         27
...
0021 opt_aset         <callinfo!mid:[]=, argc:2, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
```

The `FCALL` flag identifies a call with an implicit receiver (`foo()`); without `FCALL`, the call is to an explicit receiver (`self.foo()` or `bar.foo()`), which is prohibited by `private` methods.

Now, why 2.3.0 does this... No idea.

Comment: @KarthikT: With some additional testing, does not work in 2.3.0 or 2.1.1 (by my tests) nor in 1.9.3 (by yours), but it does work in 2.2.4 (according to EDIT: user1934428) or 2.2.4 and JRuby 1.7.11. Very inconsistent ... Possibly an old bug squashed in 2.2 making a comeback in 2.3?

Comment: @Amadan I do not confirm 2.2.4, that was user1934428

Answer (score 2):

> I assumed that  `self[:b] ||= <x>` is just syntactic sugar for `self[:b] || self[:b] = <x>`

Yes it is. But that does not mean that it rewrites the code in place, like a preprocessor. It is expanded within Ruby core code, and I guess that is not subject to the rule that allows explicit `self` with a private method. Perhaps you can look into [that feature](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11297) again.

Comment: Ah interesting... But I can do private methods on self and on 1.9.3. which is older than that feature ..

Comment: Good find, @sawa. OP, in that feature request, they do talk about exceptions that have to be handled regarding private writers and operators, in the then-current (and presumably now-current as well) codebase.